# Help on a small proof of a theorem.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$\def\di\{\mbox{div}} \def\n{\nabla}$
I'd like help  to undertand the small proof of the theorem 5.2 [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00526-006-0060-y) (dowload). How can I see that
\begin{equation}
0 = \int_{\{\xi > 0\}}\di  \left \{ \Bigl( \dfrac{1}{2} \langle A \n \xi, \n \xi  \rangle + \Gamma \Bigr) \psi - \langle \psi , \n \xi \rangle A \n \xi  \right\}dx
\end{equation}

**My thougths are that**

\begin{eqnarray*}
0& =&  \lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{E_0(\xi_\gamma , \Omega) - E_0(\xi,\Omega)}{\gamma} \\
&=& \lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 0} \Bigr(  \int_{\{\xi >0\}} \left \{  \dfrac{1}{2}  \langle A \n \xi, \xi \rangle 
+ \Gamma \right \} \di(\psi)dx \\
& &+ \int_{\{\xi >0\}} \left \{ \dfrac{1}{2} \langle (DA) \psi \n \xi,\n \xi \rangle - \langle A \n \xi , D \psi \n \xi \rangle + \langle \n \Gamma , \psi \rangle  \right \}dx  \Bigr)\\
&=&\int_{\{\xi > 0\}}\di \left \{  \Bigl( \dfrac{1}{2} \langle A \n \xi, \n \xi  \rangle + \Gamma \Bigr) \psi - \langle \psi , \n \xi \rangle A \n \xi \right\}dx
\end{eqnarray*}

Then I imagine that  zero is the limit when   $ \gamma \rightarrow 0$ in the expression below

\begin{array}{l}
\int_{\{\xi > 0\}}\di  \left\{ \Bigl( \dfrac{1}{2} \langle A \n \xi, \n \xi  \rangle + \Gamma \Bigr) \psi - \langle \psi , \n \xi \rangle A \n \xi  \right\}dx = \\ 
\int_{\{\xi > 0\}}\Bigl( \dfrac{1}{2} \langle A \n \xi, \n \xi  \rangle +  \Gamma \Bigr) \di (\psi)dx + \int_{\{\xi > 0\}}\langle \n \Bigl( \dfrac{1}{2} \langle A \n \xi, \n \xi  \rangle + \Gamma \Bigr), \n \psi \rangle dx \\
-\int_{\{\xi > 0\}}\langle \psi , \n \xi \rangle \di (A \n \xi )dx-\int_{\{\xi > 0\}} \langle  \n \Bigr( \langle \psi ,  \n \xi \rangle \Bigl), A \n \xi \rangle dx =\\
  \int_{\{\xi > 0\}} \Bigl( \dfrac{1}{2} \langle A \n \xi, \n \xi  \rangle +  \Gamma \Bigr) \di (\psi) dx + \\
 \int_{\{\xi > 0\}} \dfrac{1}{2} \langle( D(A \n \xi) \n \xi ,\n \psi \rangle dx  + \int_{\{\xi > 0\}} \dfrac{1}{2}\langle A \n \xi D^{2} \xi,\n \psi \rangle dx  + \int_{\{\xi > 0\}} \langle \Gamma, \n \psi \rangle dx \\
 -\int_{\{\xi > 0\}} \langle \psi , \n \xi \rangle \di (A \n \xi ) dx - \int_{\{\xi > 0\}} \langle D \psi  \n \xi, A \n \xi \rangle dx  -\int_{\{\xi > 0\}} \langle D² \xi \psi , A \n \xi \rangle dx
\end{array}

Then  I must to show that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_{\{\xi >0\}}  \dfrac{1}{2} \langle (DA) \psi \n \xi,\n \xi \rangle dx  &=&     \int_{\{\xi > 0\}} \dfrac{1}{2} \langle( D(A \n \xi) \n \xi ,\n \psi \rangle dx  + \int_{\{\xi > 0\}} \dfrac{1}{2}\langle A \n \xi D^{2} \xi,\n \psi \rangle dx\\
&-& \int_{\{\xi > 0\}} \langle \psi , \n \xi \rangle \di (A \n \xi ) dx  -\int_{\{\xi > 0\}} \langle D² \xi \psi , A \n \xi \rangle dx
 \end{eqnarray*}

Am I riht? Im particular, I don't get this equality, I don't know what means $DA$. The signal $D$ is used to denote  the jacobian. But $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you post a different link to the article, possible the springer 'description' page instead of directly to the fulltext?

Comment: I get an "error occurred" message in my browser, when clicking on the link, just now.

Comment: Ok.I will try correct this now.

Comment: Please, try to do dowlnload now. If not get. Please. say me.